# Indicator plugin crashing

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

I'm using Linux Mint 18.1 Serena.

After logging into my account, a graphical glitch (multiple jumbled up images of the log in screen) appeared before showing the desktop. Then appears a notification saying indicator plugin has unexpectedly left the panel and restarted more than once in the last 60 seconds. Attempts to execute it again failed, and I was forced to remove it from the panel.

I am unable to start Firefox and Thunderbird, but I do not know if this is caused by the Indicator plugin or another symptom of a deeper problem. However most other applications work normally, and I have access to the network.

A widely recommended fix is hiding the application menu indicator within the indicator plugin preferences (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499617/workaround-for-the-xfce-indicator-plugin)). However, I am unable to edit the preferences of the indicator plugin item because it crashes instantly after being added to the panel. I am at loss as of what to do next.

Thanks in advance.